# What is the difference between linear regression on two time periods with a time dummy variable and two separate regressions for each time?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, panel-data

I have panel data with two time periods on individuals aged 50+. I am interested to see if if the coefficients on dependent variables $X_{it}$ (e.g, age, gender, health) change from one time period to another. To this end, I run a regression on both time periods and include a time dummy variable, which equals to 1 if the respondent is from the second time period. The outcome variable is binary.

My regression looks something like this:

$$
y_{it} = \beta_0 + \gamma X_{it} + \delta (X_{it} \times time) + \varepsilon_{it}
$$

I have also tried running a regression for each time period separately and compared the coefficient on $X_{i1}$ and $X_{i2}$.
$$
y_{i1} = \beta_0 + \gamma X_{i1} + \varepsilon_{i1},
$$
$$
y_{i2} = \beta_0 + \theta X_{i2} + \varepsilon_{i2}
$$
The coefficient are the same as in the first regression, but the standard errors are different. Can someone explain why the standard errors changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual OLS standard error for a coefficient depends on the estimate of the standard deviation of the error, $\hat\sigma$, which will vary between the two formulations. That is, the estimate of $\hat\sigma$ will differ between the pooled regression and the split regressions. Even if they two time points have the same true standard deviation of the error, slight differences due to sampling error will yield different value of $\hat\sigma$ and therefor different standard errors for the coefficients.

But the OLS standard error isn't the only game in town; other ways of computing it are not sensitive to this problem. For example, sandwich standard errors are not sensitive to this; they are computed directly from the residuals of each model, which, given that the parameter estimates are the same across models, are also the same across models. Bootstrap standard errors are another type that are not sensitive to this; given that the bootstrap standard errors depend directly on the coefficient estimates, two model formulas that yield the exact same coefficient estimates will also yield the same bootstrap standard errors (assuming the same seed is set with both or the standard errors for both are computed in the same bootstrap procedure).

In R, to request sandwich standard errors, you can either use `estimatr::lm_robust()`, which automatically applies them, or use `lmtest::coeftest(., vcov. = sandwich::vcovHC)`, which applies sandwich robust standard errors (by default the "HC3" type) to a model fit with `lm()`.